# RHEL HA cluster, is it possible to get a notification upon failover

Tags: linux, high-availability, rhel7

I have configured Linux HA cluster on RHEL 7.1, can i get a notification upon failover or is it possible to start the crashed resource automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Pacemaker as RedHat Cluster is no longer the default HA solution for RHEL, check the logs at /var/log/cluster for anything related with a failover. As far as I know Pacemaker do several tries to get up the failing resource before marking it as failed.

Comment: yes,  I am using  HA add-on that comes with RHEL 7 which is using pcs and corosync. I am not able to verify if the HA add on does try to restart,  since I am not able to shutdown the resource(httpd).